# Static React Project, pass value from nav menu to component and from component to nav menu

Tags: reactjs

I have a route that has a custom url append and I would like to pass a value to attach to the state of the component. Then a function within that component that I would like to pass the value of that state back up to route or rather, at least change the URL.

So, a route with a path like this...

```
<Route path="/exchange/:address" component={Exchange} />
```

and a function within that Exchange component that I would like to either pass a value up to the route and refresh the page or rather just change the URL. The URL or navigation from the route, should upon lookup pass that state value into the component to render what it needs to.

```
searchToken = (event) => {
        this.setState({foo: event});
        //pass foo to route or change URL with foo as address
    }
```

To add, my site is static and I a using Hashrouter and will have to for the foreseeable future. Am I stuck having to use Redux? Or using some sort of hook like history? What would be the simplest solution here, I believe there are a few to my understanding.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the use case for pass state to and back from a component? Can easily be done using `getDerviedStateFromProps`.

Comment: you can do this.props.history.push(`/exchange/${event.target.value}`); ( add it inside template literals ) and in the Exchange component you can access the param as this.props.match.params.address you will be able to see the foo value

Answer (score 0):

```
this.props.history.push(`/exchange/${this.state.searchTokenAddress}`);
```

As Dileep Thomas said, I pushed through history into the searchToken function and got the intended results.